# Generating Gradle Signing report raising error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-wrapper

OS: MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1

Android Studio Version: Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2

When i am generating gradle signing report with

```
./gradlew signingreport
```

it gives me build error each time.

```
./gradlew signingreport

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'CampusFriends'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.2.2
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 328ms
```

Java Version

```
java -version
  java version "1.8.0_401"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_401-b10)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.401-b10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You seem to use a new Android gradle plugin version but still use Java/JDK 8 which won't work as Java/JDK 11 or 17 is required. Change the gradle JDK version in Android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Java/JDK to solve the issue by downloading appropriate version from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/), installing the package and rebotting the system.